# SharePoint 2013 Online adding a user to a group using a workflow

Tags: workflow, permissions, web-services, rest, designer-workflow

I am trying to add a user to a security group via a SharePoint 2013 workflow I am currently trying to do this using the `Call HTTP web service` action and I have 3 dictionary's built. All of this is done inside of an App Step.

Unfortunately I am getting an error back from the Response Content which I am having to email to myself, the error code reads:

> {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An entry without a type name was found, but no expected type was specified. To allow entries without type information, the expected type must also be specified when the model is specified."}}}**

This is currently how my workflow looks:
[image: Call HTTP web service]
My call to the web service looks like the followingand I am currently using **POST** as the Request Type

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('group name')/users
```

Inside of all of the dictionary's I have the following:
[image: Dictionary's]

The LoginName string is set to be the user who created the current item in that list. This will be the login name of that current user.

I have had this issue for over 3 days and if anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `__metadata`? Two underscores, not one.

Comment: That is perfect it worked, I am not unfortunately getting a new error message:

**{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}**

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Also a user wouldn't necessarily have permission to add themselves to a group, you would need some sort of permission elevation to do that

Comment: The workflow is running in App Step, this should elevate users permissions!

Comment: Did you enable app permissions for workflow, and then give it manage permissions on the web?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that the app permissions for workflow has been enabled.  I have also given the workflows manage permissions but I am still getting access denied even with the entire workflow inside an App step.

Comment: I think, you have to grant permissions to the workflow app on your root site.

Comment: Hi Roman, 
I tried the PlumSail actions pack but as this is not a free product it is not suitable for our client. I have granted the workflows permissions at the root of the site and activated the site feature but still no luck.

Comment: @Adam13Hylo Using "parameters" Build, I am not able to update "People/Group" and "Hyperlink" columns. Whereas single line of text,multiple lines of text,number, choice columns are working fine. Is it a bug or am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would like suggest to use 3rd party solution [Workflow Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) to solve this task. 
It contains [Add User to SharePoint Group](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/permissions-management/#AddUserToGroup) workflow action.

Moreover it allows you dramatically extend functionality of SharePoint Designer, because it contains more than sixty additional workflow actions.

Please have a look at full list of workflow action in [documentation section](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/).

I have to mention that I one of developers of this product and I'm very proud for our product and our customer service.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. First Build: Accept and Content-Type
2. Second Build: type
3. Third Build: __metadata and LoginName

Comment: Using Third Build, I am not able to update "People/Group" and "Hyperlink" columns. Is it a bug or am i doing anything wrong?